# Access camera menu from Canon EDSDK

Tags: edsdk

What I actually want is to select exposure type (auto or manual) when shooting video by the means of EDSDK.

I can do it using camera menu.

I didn't managed to find a way to do it from official documentation. My another try was to check all camera events when I use camera buttons to set menu options hoping there were some undocumented properties - this attempt faild too.

A generalized question would be is there a way to set menu options of camera using EDSDK i guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Modes :
>   0 = Program
>   9 = Auto
>   5 = A-DEP

programmatically, read the property can use `EdsGetPropertyData` and for set the value `EdsSetPropertyData`

```
uint emode = 5;
error = EDSDK.EdsSetPropertyData(Camera, EDSDK.PropID_AEMode, 
                                         0, sizeof(uint), emode);
```

Comment: Thanx, but it changes exposition mode of picture shooting not video. By the way when I change video exposition mode thru camera menu both `kEdsPropID_AFMode` and `kEdsPropID_AFModeSelect` stay at value `20` in both modes.